# CursorAdapter vs ArrayAdapter for a ListView

Tags: android, json, listview, android-arrayadapter, android-cursoradapter

I want to fill my `ListView` with data that's going to come from the web in the form of JSON. The list should be theoretically infinite, with the app making requests for more data if scrolled to the bottom.

- Should I use a `Cursor` or an `Array(List)` adapter to link my online database with my `ListView`?
- More generally, what are the arguments to consider when choosing between **cursor** and **array**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well I think you should look at `ContentProviders`. They are more natural to the problem that you are trying to solve. You have to implement your custom `Cursor` which `ContentProvider` returns on a query request.

Ref:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html