# What is advantage Cursor Adapter over Array Adapter?

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-cursoradapter

I am little bit confused to use which adapter best for me to retrieve data from a .mp3 file like Art, SongName, Artist etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Better to use Cursor adapter or Array adapter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21130162/better-to-use-cursor-adapter-or-array-adapter)

Comment: Do you have a database or array of items? `if(database) { cursorAdapter } else { arrayAdapter }`

Comment: That `CursorAdapter` doesn't require you to load the entire database into memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CursorAdapter` is more appropriate when there is a database because it does not load all the records as `ArrayAdapter`. It loads only the visible records.